# Mod Rewrite does not work when URI folder not exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

`http://site.loc/` works fine

`http://site.loc/books` not working

.htaccess URL Rewrite failing on localhost with a 404 error

> The requested URL /books was not found on this server

I just reinstalled Sierra and setup PHP & Apache, and facing above error, here is my simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?!=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is the CustomLog

```
localhost - - [26/Mar/2017:21:30:08 +0300] "GET /books/ HTTP/1.1" 404 204
```

**NOTE** same `.htaccess` is working right now in production without issues, and it has worked on another local environment before.

Tried 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Tried 2:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
```

Also changed this in httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and also `rewrite_module` is enabled

Please share your thoughts ;) what I am missing here? thanks in advance.

Comment: why RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?!=$1 [QSA,L]?? Can you try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L] or RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: tried both, does not work :( `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?!=$1 [QSA,L]` is for the reason that all uri params such as /a/b/c to be passed in `$_GET[!]`, I am sure its not the problem, it worked before on my previous localhost, currently same htaccess works on production. i guess messed something in one of .conf while setting up new environment

Comment: Why not enable debug logging? `LogLevel info rewrite:trace8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by adding following Directory directive in vhosts.conf

```
<Directory "/path/to/site">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

To see how the full `VirtualHost` directive looks, follow the screenshot below ;)

[image]